# Cannot get value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I seem to be having a problem checking if a string exists in my array. There is probably a really obvious answer to my question do forgive me but I'm new to PHP.

Anyway here is my code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row;
}

if (in_array("496891", $result_array)) 
{
echo "true";
}
else
{
echo "false";
}
```

The array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 496891 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 1177953 ))
```

My code always echoes false. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: in_array only checks the "first" level of a array. You have a multidimensional one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested array and must check against each item like so:

```
function in_multidimensional_array($val, $array) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
     if (in_array($val, $array[$key])) {
        return true;
     }  
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now you can check if the value `496891` exists using:

```
if(in_multidimensional_array('496891', $result_array)) {
   print 'true';
} else {
   print 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Krister's solution only works if you only have one row in your MySQL-loop. This would check against all the results.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row;
}

$found = false;
foreach ($result_array as $v) {
    if (in_array("496891", $v)) {
        $found = true;
    }
}

if ($found == true)
    echo 'true';
else
    echo 'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a string, but your array is holding numeric values. You would need to make sure that you insert it specifically as a string to get it to return true, or each field as a string prior to the search.